# Bootstrap 4 отключить адаптацию ниже 1200

Tags: адаптивность, bootstrap4

Доброго времени суток...
Случилась такая проблема, я не ожидал что это станет проблемой, так как на 3 отключал всё легко,
тут же несколько часов плясок на костылях не дают вообще результата
есть сайт его рабочее пространство это 1200-1920 ниже не должно ничего адаптироваться, но как бы я не задавал ширину контейнерам он всё равно адаптируется и сетка тупо валится так как не рассчитана она на меньшее и не должна быть рассчитана.
точнее если контейнерам ширину указать, всё нормально, ширина контейнеров нормальная, а вот дальше col`ы валятся
Как зафиксироваться на ширине 1200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что там медиазапросы написаны не только на родительский контейнер, который вы пытаетесь "зафиксировать", а на все колонки (col), которые так же меняют свою ширину в % в зависимости от ширины экрана (между прочим, в 3 тоже самое). Проще скомпилировать бутстрап заново и указать все необходимые параметры breackpoint-ов сетки которые нужны.

Comment: Я пытался менять брекпоинты но результата так же не получил.
именно через scss может подскажите что конкретно поменять чтобы такого добиться?

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал перекомпилировать бутстрап заново и указать там нужные параметры. Если не вариант, то попробовать зафиксировать так же значения ширины колонок на нужном разрешении в медиазапросе. Вы же говорите что блок удалось зафиксировать, но сами колонки меняют размер? Вся причина в том, что на колонки тоже есть медиазапросы и их тоже можно изменить.

Comment: я думал есть более без костыльный способ, пришлось всем колонкам задавать минимальную ширину и контейнерам, более менее зафиксировалось